# Pequena dúvida com operações numéricas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estava fazendo uma função em python que me retorne os resultados(x' e x") da fórmula de bhaskara, só pra treinar a lógica um pouquinho. E brincando um pouco no shell, acabei descobrindo uma coisa estranha. Não é nada de mais, mas me deixou curioso.

Se eu elevar um número negativo ao quadrado, o esperado é que o resultado seja positivo, né?

```
>>> -7 ** 2
-49
```

Não é o que acontece se eu fizer da forma acima. Entretanto, se eu atribuir o `-7` a uma variável `x`, por exemplo, e tentar elevar `x` ao quadrado...

```
>>> x  = -7
>>> x ** 2
49
```

...o resultado sai como o esperado. Por que o python não fez a operação corretamente do primeiro modo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pelo que parece o operador `**` possui precedência maior que o operador unário `-`, ou seja, primeiro o interpretador calcula a potência e depois a negativa. Assim sendo a expressão `-7 ** 2` seria equivalente a `-(7 ** 2)`, o que resulta em `-49`.

Se você for pensar bem, é o que ocorre normalmente quando estamos operando expressões matemáticas, numa folha de papel:

- -7<sup>2</sup> é de fato -49
- (-7)<sup>2</sup> esse sim seria 49

Comment: Entendi, mas ainda sim acho estranho, pois eu não explicitei os parênteses para deixar o sinal negativo de fora. Eu achava até que isso poderia ser algum tipo de bug.

Comment: É uma questão de notação matemática mesmo. A potência possui maior precedência. Se o sinal de negativo tivesse maior precedência, então **-x²** seria igual a **(-x)²** que seria igual a **x²**. Se isso fosse verdade uma equação que normalmente se escreve **-x² = -1**, teria de ser escrita como **-(x²) = -1**.